# AUTO Sign in to facebook iphone

Tags: facebook, api, authentication

I am developing an app for iphone which needs to read all the information from a particular group for which I am a member. Is it possible to auto sign and get access token and access the group information on Facebook and display to user. I don't mind saving  my login credentials in code. I want users to get a smooth experience with no hassles of logging in.

Is this possible ..??? How ?

THanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

you can try [_session resume] using this if once user logged in then app won't ask again for login until you forcefully logout the user using [_session logout]. For more info download facebook ios sdk from github and try to read the sample app.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But to create the session do we need to manually login once...???